# Access YouTube Video URL With YouTube Video ID

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm currently working on a Web project that uses YouTube API.

I am completely unfamiliar with the API. So a lot of effort was needed for each line of code.

Using following code I can retrieve items in a playlist successfully:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&playlistId=a&key=b

I receive a JSON file like this

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/Wz7cvzuMs_tcayBMxW0Zfi_seVE\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": "7",
        "resultsPerPage": "5"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/XqXewlxjMltQNRFVLLHsWClvl0o\"",
            "id": "PLTkKeV68Awyfb3jUTWipVt1po4PRMLkegNZJmJyZT7sY"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/YQ1fBRcQrALULNJik38Bg2I7od8\"",
            "id": "PLTkKeV68Awyfb3jUTWipVt7aZNlECmRHa8IJ-kAFkmJs"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/WV3S-Lii4Xys27YNFOVDVs_kvpM\"",
            "id": "PLTkKeV68Awyfb3jUTWipVt3LY0ze6_BKXezp3JVY62uQ"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/R-YeNXuuTjStx4OmGdDdYEpaXxw\"",
            "id": "PLTkKeV68Awyfb3jUTWipVt7X1fr2iJ7kLfDFmJ_V_D0o"
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/IF2GQMx3AhGIntV_58dXWyH0Wtc\"",
            "id": "PLTkKeV68Awyfb3jUTWipVt-vwlWFevATj923vR9_d5Ko"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you take a look at JSON result,You'll see that each item has an ID.
What should I do with this ID to get URL associated with that?

Comment: Please include the code in your question, rather than link to an external site.  Otherwise, years from now when somebody has this same problem, those links could be broken and that person will go away sad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first call was right, only you need the snippet as well to get the video IDs.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id,snippet&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key=KEY`

Put the above in your browser to see the JSON result. You'll want to grab the

`snippet->resourceId->videoID`

for each item. Once you have the videoID you can make the url by just adding it to the end of the string "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="

I think that's what you were asking for.

Comment: I don't know how may I thank you. You got what I exactly needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ['list' API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get details about an individual video, through this url:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

It accepts an "id" parameter that takes in the video id you want info about, and it returns a [Video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) that includes any info you specify in the "part" parameter that you want to receive.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work;What wrong with this : `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=PLTkKeV68Awyfb3jUTWipVt1po4PRMLkegNZJmJyZT7sY&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: It needs to be an ID of a video, not a playlist.